# Java Commenting Conventions

Tags: java, comments

Which method of commenting is most widely accepted or does it really matter?

I have been using

```
/**  
 * (Method description)
 * @param
 * @return
 * etc
 */
```

However I have read of:

```
Precondition:
Postcondition:
```

Is there a more 'professional' way of commenting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Commenting Conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999431/commenting-conventions)

Answer (score 21):

Here are the Java coding conventions for comments recommended by Oracle:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-141999.html#385

Here are Google's recommendations for their Android platform:

- https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#use-javadoc-standard-comments

For more detailed information on style and conventions for Javadoc, see here:

- [How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)

Comment: The link to Google recommendations seems to be gone or restricted.  Maybe this is the replacement? http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#use-javadoc-standard-comments

Comment: I think Javadoc conventions are  the best. Does anyone have the Oracle recommendations pdf or new address?

Answer (score 1):

The comment style in your first example is not just a convention, it is a standard for a documentation tool called [Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html). If you follow that Javadoc commenting style, you will be able to easily generate html formatted documentation for all of your source code.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) link is very useful  and i have been using this for a long time and has helped me a lot. This creates a very good and documented code with maximum readiblity.

Answer (score 1):

First off all having readable code and readable comments are two things that are totally different.

Readable code is code the uses good variable, method, class names, etc.

Readable comments are more a matter of personal taste. Some people like comments to follow grammatical rules that would be used to write a book while others couldn't care less about grammatical stuff. You can go through this link:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-141999.html#385

From readable code and comments, you can create documentation with the help of doxygen.

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html

Answer (score 0):

I would simply follow standard defined by Sun (Oracle) for writing Javadoc. Javadoc is referred by all developers unanimously :). For more information click [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)

I would also ask you to do following [search on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=commenting) for lots of questions and ansers on commenting.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=commenting